# Binding one view datacontext to mainwindows datacontext

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Me and my friend have a mainwindow with two grid rows and each row are supposed to represent a different view. The top view is a navigationbar that we want to be exchangeable according to what authorizationlevel you have and thus be able to access different content.

We have one view that's in another namespace named OperatorNavView where the code looks like this

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel x:Name="NavBar" Orientation="Horizontal" Height="75" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="White" Grid.Row="0">
        <Button x:Name="btnTeams" Content="Lag"  Command="{Binding NavigationCommand}" CommandParameter="Team" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="77"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="#d87900" Height="44" />
        <Button x:Name="btnAchievements" Content="Utmärkelser" Command="{Binding NavigationCommand}" CommandParameter="Achievements" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="91" Background="#c20071" Height="44"/>
        <Button x:Name="btnNotifications" Content="Notifikations&#xD;&#xA;inställningar&#xD;&#xA;" Command="{Binding NavigationCommand}" CommandParameter="Notification" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Background="#95b800" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="83" Height="44"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

The bindings on the commands refer to the mainwindows viewmodel "MainWindowViewModel"

I need to connect the datacontext from the mainviewmodel to the UserControl which is my view. I have tried various techniques such as writing in codebehind

```
DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();
```

which does not work, my guess is that it's because it's a new instance and does not show the changes.

The buttons on the usercontrol is supposed to display a second view. the MainWindow xaml looks like this

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="75" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Row="0">
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentNavBar}" />
        <Button x:Name="button" Command="{Binding AuthorizationCommand}" Content="hej" CommandParameter="Operator" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="26,27,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
    </Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentViewModel}" />

    </Grid>
```

Comment: Have you tried relativesource binding?

Comment: I have not tried that yet.

Comment: I couldn't get it to work, do you have an example for me? I attempted with a relative source binding on the datacontext setting for ContentControl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in a relativesource binding as Abhinav Sharma suggested.
I added the relativesource binding to the datacontext of the stackpanel in this way:

```
<StackPanel x:Name="NavBar" Orientation="Horizontal" Height="75" VertcalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="White" 
Grid.Row="0" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext}" >
```